# Самоучители Delphi для чайников =)

Tags: delphi, pascal

Ребята, я так говоря новичок в
кодовых  и языковых средах РК,
помогите найти  самоучители, уроки,
либо курсы и т.д.  Буду благодарен.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да этих книг хоть пруд-пруди! Бери поиcковик и вперед. Рекомендую авторов Бобровский и Фаронов - по ним сам учил Delphi 7.